# Session preview returns error: invallid null link

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

When updating the preview (either by clicking on 'Update Preview' or by saving changes) I get the following error:

[image]

In the console of chrome I see the following error

[image]

I checked the file system and Services.svc is in the right location.

The good old Event Viewer also noticed this error
[image]

Is this a configuration problem or an infrastructure problem? Does anyone recognize this issue?

Hope you can lead me to a solution, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried giving it a valid null link? j/k

Comment: It seems that it was unable to figure out the URI of (some of) the items. Could you check the request to that web service call and see which variable was null? That would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Haha, lol needed that ;)
I found the solution, some templateIDs where null in the request, because that components didn't have a component template. Thank you for the hint (and the joke)!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help a little :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peter Kjaer and Bart Koopman gave the right hints. When I checked the POST request (using the 'Network' tab in Google Chrome), I saw the following:

[image]

Some TemplateId's were 'null'. This is because that components didn't have a component template.

In my DD4T view I created the XPM tag manually because there is no Component Presentation for this component.

In that tag I only specified the Component Id

```
        @Html.Raw("<!-- Start Component Presentation: {'ComponentID' : '" + footer.Id + "' } -->")
```

To fix this, I created a 'Dummy' Component Template and I am using that ID now as TemplateID for the components that don't have a Component Template, like this:

```
@Html.Raw("<!-- Start Component Presentation: {'ComponentID' : '" + footer.Id + "' 'ComponentTemplateID' : '" + DummyCTID + "'  } -->")
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in debugging this, but the error sounds to me like you might have an invalid Component link in your content.

I've seen a similar issue before where the content of a Component was invalid, while the SDL Tridion UI still found it acceptable, the XPM Session Preview OData service couldn't hande it.

So I would first check the HTML source of this page and validate that all XPM comments have valid URIs specified, and then check the actual content on the Page.

Perhaps good to start with a simple reproduction scenario, is this reproducible on every Page, even on empty Pages? Or is it only a specific Page or Component Presentation that causes this?

Comment: Thank you Bart, I found the solution. Some of my XPM tags where missing a templateID